# Kafka AVRO special character serialisation

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I have a JAVA springboot project, pushing avro messages in kafka.
During my development, using a windows PC, all my messages in kafka appeared right with all special character (é, à, ...)

Using the following serializer :

```
key-serializer: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
value-serializer: "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
```

After using unix to compile and deploy my JAR on artifactory, my messages don't show as expected.

Using a Kafka console consumer, all special character turn into ��. And I can't find the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour using `kafka-console-consumer`

You should be using `kafka-avro-console-consumer` instead to properly deserialize Confluent Schema-Registry Avro payloads